# Wordpress alternative, modern code base, OOP, MVC

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a simple blog (not a huge CMS) application that is similiar to wordpress, just categories, pages and a gallery. Nothing fancy that I need.

I really dislike Wordpress, it's code just sucks. I'm looking for a more modern blog software that is not from the stoneage of PHP and software architecture. I would prefer something that follows the MVC design pattern and is object oriented programmed.

Any suggestions based on these requirements?

Comment: Why not build your own in Django or Ruby? There are plenty of fast tutorials and samples out there for the Googling

Comment: I'm not going to learn another language and I have no interest in spending hours in building something like that. I already run my own open source projects. Funny that the question got closed, it is very specific... These QA sites are really full of smart ass people.

Comment: I assumed from your question that you didn't like PHP in general so I was suggesting MVC frameworks that I know to have a lot of ready-to-deploy blog code posted out there.  As for wh it got closed, I'm assuming it's because you are asking for opinion-based ("which is best") recommendations and there's no true answer.

Comment: @JCL1178 That is not true, he isn't asking for the best, only an alternative CMS like Wordpress (blog) without the procedural code but OOP MVC pattern. I agree with the OP, wordpress code is ugly and there are almost no way for unit testing. Also Wordpress is full of hard coded settings and you will find exceptions, javascript and inline styling everywhere! Additional, I find HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP in the same files mixed up!

Comment: @Bondye Don't blame me, I didn't close the question or even flag it to be closed.  Also, opinions on WordPress's suckability or lack thereof are largely moot...it's here, it's common, and it's unlikely to be going anywhere anytime soon.  If you don't like it, don't use it!

Comment: @JCL1178 `If you don't like it, don't use it!` That is why the OP is looking for an alternative ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [PyroCMS](https://www.pyrocms.com/), and I can recommend it.

While not just for blogging, it supports it well, it's highly configurable, and it's LAMP based so it's easy to set up. It has a blogging system, categories, and a gallery module you can download.

It makes the most of MVC and OOP principles, and it's really easy to extend with plugins, modules and helpers.

You won't have any of the frankencode that can result from a Wordpress install that has far too much asked of it.